# Codeigniter trouble sending php var into javascript and .load content

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Im having troubles sending a variable from php to javascript.

I pull javascript (Ajax) trough this link.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/main.js' ?>"></script>
```

In my `main.js` :

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
var language = '<?php echo $language; ?>';
```

Im trying to load content dynamically without refresh webpage, by using ajax `.load` this way:

```
var addressValue = $(this).children('a').attr("href");

$('#conteudo').fadeOut("slow").load(addressValue+'/index.php?idioma='+language+' #conteudo').hide().fadeIn("slow")
```

I can load perfectly with the `addressValue` onyl.
But when i try the way above, my language won't echo.
If instead of using `language`  i put the language i want without variable e.g. portuguese it works like a charm.
im working with multilanguage so i need to pull the content in the language the user did choose.

This is how user can set language

```
<ul class="nav pull-right language" id="barra_de_idiomas">
    <li><?php echo anchor(($this->uri->uri_string())."?idioma=english",'&nbsp;', 'class="language" id="en"') ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor(($this->uri->uri_string())."?idioma=portuguese",'&nbsp;', 'class="language" id="pt"') ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor(($this->uri->uri_string())."?idioma=german",'&nbsp;', 'class="language" id="de"') ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor(($this->uri->uri_string())."?idioma=french",'&nbsp;', 'class="language" id="fr"') ?></li>
</ul>
```

And my construct from controller:

```
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    if ($this->config->item('language') == '') {
        if($this->input->get('idioma') == true) {
            $this->config->set_item('language', $this->input->get('idioma'));
        } elseif ($this->agent->accept_lang('en')) {
            $this->config->set_item('language', 'english');
        } elseif ($this->agent->accept_lang('de')) {
            $this->config->set_item('language', 'german');
        } elseif ($this->agent->accept_lang('pt')) {
            $this->config->set_item('language', 'portuguese');
        } else {
            $this->config->set_item('language', 'portuguese');
        }
    }
    $language = $this->config->item('language');
    $data['language'] = $language;
    $this->load->vars($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest to you make use of `base_url()` like:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/main.js') ?>"></script>
```

Second, you are not able to use php code in javascript files as you are doing at `main.js`:

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
var language = '<?php echo $language; ?>';
```

One alternative is print the javascript variables before to `main.js` invocation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
    var language = '<?php echo $language; ?>';
</script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/main.js') ?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you're trying to use PHP tags in your JavaScript file? That won't work unless your server is set up to pass the `.js` request to a PHP file first, then the PHP is delivered as JavaScript.

The easiest way to get those values from PHP to JavaScript would be to set them as attributes of some element on your page, and select them as you did with `addressValue`.